# Question about law of iterated expectations?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have this question:

Let Y = a + bX + U, where X and U are random variables and a and b are constants.Assume that E(U|X) = 0, and that Var(X) > 0.

I need to find E[UX]

The answer is zero, found by E[X*E[U|X]]

Where I'm having the problem is, why is the solution not given by E[X] * E[U|X]? Is there a formula that I'm missing? Please help if possible!

Answer (score 0):

> Where I'm having the problem is, why is the solution not given by E[X] * E[U|X]? Is there a formula that I'm missing? Please help if possible!

$\mathsf E(UX)$ is a constant, as is $\mathsf E(X)$.

$\mathsf E(U\mid X)$ is a random variable, as is the product $\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(U\mid X)$.

Clearly a constant is not generally equal to a random variable (unless it's a monatomic random variable).

However $\mathsf E\big(X \mathsf E(U\mid X)\big)$ is a constant.

Let's put 'training wheels' on the expectations to see why.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E_{U,X}(UX) & = \mathsf E_X(\mathsf E_{U\mid X}(UX\mid X)) 
& \text{Law of Iterated Expectation}
\\ & = \mathsf E_X(X\mathsf E_{U\mid X}(U\mid X))
\end{align}$$

The 'training wheel' subscripts are used make explicit the density function used in the integration of the expectation.   They are often redundant but *sometimes* helpful to students.   So this corresponds to :

$$\begin{align}
\iint_{U,X} ux f_{U,X}(u,x) \operatorname d u \operatorname d x & = \int_X \int_{U\mid X=x}u xf_{U\mid X}(u\mid x)f_X(x)\operatorname d u\operatorname d x
\\ & = \int_X x f_X(x)\int_{U\mid X=x}u f_{U\mid X}(u\mid x)\operatorname d u\operatorname d x
\end{align}$$

Hence without the 'training wheels' we have:
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(UX) & = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(UX\mid X)) 
\\ & = \mathsf E(X\mathsf E(U\mid X))
\end{align}$$

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you!